# ASP.NET 5 RC1 Entity Framework 7 - custom identity issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create my custom identity implementation to use int values for my primary keys insted of default strings in ASP.NET 5 RC1 with EF7.
I have my custom User and Role classes as well as UserStore, UserManager, RoleStore, RoleManager. For now I have issues with UserStore being ***Unable to resolve service for type 'DAL.BgCarsDbContext' while attempting to activate 'DAL.Identity.UserStore'.***

[image]

My code for User and UserStore classes:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
}

public class UserStore : UserStore<User, Role, BgCarsDbContext, int>
{
    public UserStore(BgCarsDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) 
        : base(context, describer)
    {
    }
}
```

I know that's happening because of the default UserStore behaviour.

[image]

However, I would like to use the default implementation that UserStore provides because it implements a lot of interfaces

```
IUserLoginStore<TUser>, IUserStore<TUser>, IDisposable, IUserRoleStore<TUser>, IUserClaimStore<TUser>, IUserPasswordStore<TUser>, IUserSecurityStampStore<TUser>, IUserEmailStore<TUser>, IUserLockoutStore<TUser>, IUserPhoneNumberStore<TUser>, IQueryableUserStore<TUser>, IUserTwoFactorStore<TUser>
```

and I'd like to avoid having to write the implementation of every method from the interfaces. So is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: Not sure if possible using the default implementation, but if you take a look at [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1045746/ASP-NET-Identity-with-Azure-Storage-Table) I wrote about using Identity with Azure Storage Table, you will see that it'll take a few minutes to get your custom implementation up and running

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!

Comment: I see your points, I have tried the same thing to implement interfaces myself but I hoped to avoid implementing each method since most of them would be the same...

Comment: I understand it can be frustrating, but it also allows for custom logic and easier debugging. Completing the class with methods implemented can take some... 10 minutes.